# Identity Server 4 and auto redirect on sign out

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

Playing around with a demo project from PluralSight, I am trying to have the IDP redirect back to the server app on sign out.

The **PostLogOutRedirectUris** is defined in the config for the Client at the IDP level, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
    new Client[]
    { 
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "bethanyspieshophr",
            ClientName = "Bethany's Pie Shop HRM",
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AccessTokenLifetime = 120,
            RequireConsent = false,
            RequirePkce = true,
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
            ClientSecrets = { 
                new Secret("108B7B4F-BEFC-4DD2-82E1-7F025F0F75D0".Sha256()) },
            RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44301/signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44301/signout-oidc" },
            AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "bethanyspieshophrapi" }
        }             
    };
```

If I manually at runtime set the LoggedOutViewModel it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was simply due to a typo, which sent me on a wild goose chase.

```
  PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44301/signout-oidc" },
```

Should be

```
  PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44301/signout-callback-oidc" },
```

And then, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

How are you performing the logout request? Remember that the value in the client settings is just the registered value which is verified during logout request. The user is not redirected automatically to the `postLogoutRedirectUri`. You have to pass a `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter to the end session endpoint and this parameter must match on of the values in the `PostLogoutRedirectUris` setting. To use this feature you should also post a valid ID token in the `id_token_hint` parameter, so that the server knows which client is requesting the logout.

You can have a look at the [end session enpoint docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/endsession.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but the solution was simply that I used the wrong Uri. It should be ../signout-callback-oidc. The eyes sometimes reads what you want to see, not what it actually says :)